# How to read data from BigQuery in pandas dataframe in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql, google-api-python-client

I am implementing a new end point in a python-flask API, which should take the data from BigQuery and send it to the CloudSQL(mysql). For that purpose I assume that first a connection to BigQuery needs to be established. However i am new to the cloud services and I need help... Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1):

[1] In case you still don't have a service account, you need to create it first. This article might helps: https://docs.openbridge.com/en/articles/1856793-how-to-set-up-google-bigquery-creating-and-configuring-service-accounts-in-google-cloud-console

[2] After your done with [1], you can use the BigQuery Client API to read the data from your BigQuery projects.

Read this documentation for a more complete explanation about using BigQuery Client API: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-storage-python-pandas#download_table_data_using_the_client_library